# How to store image data in a dictionary

Tags: python, image, dictionary

I'd like to store image metadata (height, width, color channels etc.) inside of a dictionary. There are multiple images so I'd want to iterate through the folder of images using Python os and create a dictionary, including the image metadata, for each image. This is some bad code which may illustrate what I mean.

```
PATH_TO_IMAGES = 'images/data'
print(os.listdir(PATH_TO_IMAGES))

list_of_images = [os.listdir(PATH_TO_IMAGES)]
for im in list_of_images:
    imdict = {}
    imdict['height'] = ???
    imdict['width'] = ???
    imdict['channels'] = ???
    imdict['name'] = ???
```

I'd also appreciate knowing which packages (PIL, matplotlib, ?) are good for this. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are tying to do.  you want a single dict that cotains all data for all images? or a new dict for each image? either way I think you have some errors.  Your "imdict = {}" gets overwritten with each loop. The print statement will only print the last image.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: I want a single dict for EACH image. I'm aware of the errors and I want the print statement to print each dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what 'channels' is, but this should get you the rest of the information you need.  Take a look at PIL.  Looks like you could also use Pillow.  I've never used it, but it claims to be easy to use.

```
import os
from PIL import Image

PATH_TO_IMAGES = 'images/'
image_paths = os.listdir(PATH_TO_IMAGES)
print(image_paths)

list_of_image_data = []
for im in image_paths:
    image = Image.open(PATH_TO_IMAGES + im)
    width, height = image.size
    imdict = {
        'name': im,
        'height': height,
        'width': width,
    }
    list_of_image_data.append(imdict)

print(list_of_image_data)
```

Comment: Gives me an error and 'image = Image.open(im)' does not work for some reason.

Comment: you're right.  I've fixed the bug.  the issue was it needed to append the path to the image name before opening.

Comment: Could you also provide a way to access the dictionary images in a loop?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Isn't this in a loop? You mean a way to access the data in `list_of_image_data`?